# Acton text, display video player with active storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage, trix, actiontext

I am using Trix editor with upload attachments functionality.

At the moment I can upload images, pdf, videos, etc... and show them after submit. Also I can have an image preview of what I uploaded.

But I don't know how to add a video player to it.

My actual _blob.html.erb looks like this:

```
<figure class="attachment attachment--<%= blob.representable? ? "preview" : "file" %> attachment--<%= blob.filename.extension %>">
    <% if blob.representable? %>
    <%= image_tag blob.representation(resize_to_fit: local_assigns[:in_gallery] ? [ 800, 600 ] : [ 1024, 768 ]) %>
    <% end %>

    <figcaption class="attachment__caption flex-1">
        <div>
        <% if caption = blob.try(:caption) %>
        <%= caption %>
        <% else %>
        <span class="attachment__name text-gray-600"><%= blob.filename %></span>
        <span class="attachment__size text-gray-600"><%= number_to_human_size blob.byte_size %></span>
        <% end %>
        </div>
         <div class="mt-6 mb-4">
        <%= link_to "View file", rails_blob_url(blob, disposition: "preview"), target: "_blank", class: "bg-gray-200 text-sm py-2 px-4 rounded mt-6" %> -
        <%= link_to "Download", rails_blob_path(blob, disposition: "attachment"), class: " text-sm bg-gray-200 py-2 px-4 rounded" %>
        </div>
    </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in your _blob:

```
 - if blob.video?
    %video(controls="true" width="100%" preload="metadata")
      %source{src: rails_blob_url(blob), type:"#{blob.content_type}"}
```

`%video` is the HTML5 video tag

Next you will need to add this to application.rb:

```
#video previews for action_text
config.after_initialize do
  ActionText::ContentHelper.allowed_attributes.add 'style'
  ActionText::ContentHelper.allowed_attributes.add 'controls'

  ActionText::ContentHelper.allowed_tags.add 'video'
  ActionText::ContentHelper.allowed_tags.add 'audio'
  ActionText::ContentHelper.allowed_tags.add 'source'
end
```

The above works for `rails 6.0.1` but might not work with `rails 6.0.3`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am quite new to rails. Would you mind share how can I write it in my _blob.html.erb I am trying something like this: 
`<% if blob.representable? %>
    <%= image_tag blob.representation(resize_to_fit: local_assigns[:in_gallery] ? [ 800, 600 ] : [ 1024, 768 ]) %>
    <% end %>
    <% if blob.video? %>
    <%= video(controls="true" width="100%" preload="metadata") source{src: rails_blob_url(blob), type:"#{blob.content_type}"} %>
    <% end %>`

Comment: it's very uncomfortable to read code in the comments :) you can transform my solution from haml to erb here: https://haml2erb.org/

Comment: `<% if blob.video? %>
  <video>(controls="true" width="100%" preload="metadata")
    <source src="<%= rails_blob_url(blob) %>" type="<%= blob.content_type %>"></source>
  </video>
<% end %>`

Comment: just FYI - I got my answer from here - https://www.udemy.com/course/ruby-on-rails-6-learn-20-gems-build-an-e-learning-platform/?referralCode=4721E9D437DEE1734159. In this course there is the most detailed practical information on using actiontext & activestorage